# Find two linearly independent functions with a zero Wronskian but a nonzero product.

Tags: real-analysis, big-list

Known to me examples of L.I. functions having Wronskian=0 have also product=0. One such example was manufactured by Peano about 1890. By the way: Analytic functions with a zero Wronskian are linearly dependent - done by Bucher in 1900. I have a proof which is a bit simpler than Bucher`s and has less than 2 pages.

Comment: When you say 'having $W=0$' do you mean over a whole (non trivial) interval?

Comment: Do you mean like the [*Note*](http://www.math.montana.edu/~campanel/m225sp07/www/ch3/wronskian.pdf) on page 2?

Comment: Yes, over any open interval

Comment: Your Note on p.2 states Peano's example.